# Silence a specific guard plugin?

Tags: ruby, guard, yard

I´m using [guard-yard](https://github.com/panthomakos/guard-yard) to automatically run YARD. However the output it has is really annoying and makes it hard to read the RSpec output (which is more interresting).

```
guard 'yard' do
  watch(%r{app/.+\.rb})
  watch(%r{lib/.+\.rb})
  watch(%r{ext/.+\.c})
end
```

**Q. How do I silence the output of this Guard plugin?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Option 1: You may want to only run Yard if the tests pass:

```
group :stuff, halt_on_fail: true do
  guard :rspec, cmd: 'bundle exec rspec' do
    # (stuff for guard-rspec template goes here
  end

  guard :yard do
    watch(%r{app/.+\.rb})
    watch(%r{lib/.+\.rb})
    watch(%r{ext/.+\.c})
  end
end
```

or ...

#### Option 2: you may prefer to just skip yard when you're focused on RSpec:

```
guard :rspec, cmd: 'bundle exec rspec' do
  # (stuff for guard-rspec template goes here
end

guard :yard do
  watch(%r{app/.+\.rb})
  watch(%r{lib/.+\.rb})
  watch(%r{ext/.+\.c})
end
```

and limit guard to just running rspec `bundle exec guard -g rspec`

#### Option 3: use the `scope` command to switch between groups/plugins

You can also use the `scope` command in the Pry interactor to tell Guard what you're interested in running, e.g.

```
# tells guard to just run rspec
[1] guard(main)> scope rspec
[2] RSpec guard(main)>

# or just yard
[1] guard(main)> scope yard
[2] Yard guard(main)>

# or everything again
[1] guard(main)> scope default
[2] Default guard(main)>
```

Answer (score 3):

The yard tool output can be redirected. AFAIK you can't disable all notifications for guard.

FWIW: This is the way I set up yard in my `Guardfile` to hide part of the output:

`guard :yard, stdout: 'log/yard.log', stderr: 'log/yard_error.log' do
    watch(%r{app/.+\.rb})
    watch(%r{lib/.+\.rb})
end`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I used interactor :off ate the beginning of the Guardfile, so your code should look like this:

```
interactor :off
guard 'yard' do
  watch(%r{app/.+\.rb})
  watch(%r{lib/.+\.rb})
  watch(%r{ext/.+\.c})
end
```

To run it in the background and not receive any output in the console you should run the command as:

```
bundle exec guard <options> >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Comment: Hi @papirtiger if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Hi, I haven't had time to try it out yet. Sorry!

Comment: Removing the interactor is not a really good solution - I actually use it quite often.